# How can I recover camera presets in blender?

Tags: camera

I was trying to reset the camera to the default setting when i click on the minus button in the camera presets located in the camera properties. I believe I deleted the samsung galaxy 4 and blender presets that came with blender. How can I recover these settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the camera presets here:

https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/presets/camera/

download the one you are [missing (Samsung_Galaxy_S4)](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/presets/camera/Samsung_Galaxy_S4.py) and place it in your

[blender]/2.77/scripts/presets/camera folder.  Where [blender] is the folder the program is in and 2.77 is the version, change to suit.

Might need to restart blender or hit F8 to reload scripts.

PS.. did same only yesterday with a different preset, kinda needs a confirm IMO.

Comment: I agree, It definitely does need a confirm. Thanks.