# I deleted a preset, but can't reobtain with Load factory settings

Tags: rendering, dimensions

In the recent version of Blender, panel *Properties*, *Render* tab, *Dimensions* section, I deleted a preset, but I can't reobtain it.

I tried this: *File > Load factory settings*, but it doesn't affect the presets.

Comment: Somewhat related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62597/how-can-i-recover-camera-presets-in-blender/62600?s=1|0.9838#62600   render presets can be found here https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/presets/render/